# Is the local or remote version of git used when pushing?

Tags: git, git-push, git-config

Git 2.3.0 added better support for "push to deploy" set-ups, using this option:

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead
```

My question is: is it the server I'm pushing to, or the client I'm pushing from that needs git v2.3.0 to honour this option? Does the protocol used to access the pushed-to repository change this? (e.g. SSH vs. the git protocol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `updateInstead` setting for `receive.denyCurrentBranch` is implemented entirely on the server (receiving) side.  Only the server needs to run 2.3.0. It doesn't matter what protocol you use.

You only need to set `updateInstead` on the server side (and probably shouldn't set it on the client side).